# php code wont work and display data

Tags: php

This code is from w3schools which displays the email address and name once the user submits the form. However when I tried copying the code it wouldn't let me display the same output and would only say **Cannot POST /welcome.php** or it would display the welcome.php code whenever i submit.

I didn't even alter it in anyway but why wont it work? D:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>  
    <body>

      <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            <input type="submit">
      </form>

    </body>
   </html>
```

**welcome.php**

```
<html>
  <body>

     Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
     Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: It sounds like PHP isn't installed

Comment: Either php is not installed on your computer or you should check if your php.ini file has track_vars disabled.

Comment: What is the actual error you're getting ?

Comment: i'm getting "Cannot POST /welcome.php" and thats it

Comment: You need to use a webserver to POST, you can't do it with local files.

Comment: You also need a webserver to run PHP.

Comment: @Barmar im actually just trying out if my php stuff works in my mac. I have this code where I wanted to display all the data from my webserver database but it wont let me connect and i wasnt sure where I was going wrong

Comment: Install MAMPP to get a webserver+PHP+MySQL configuration on your Mac.